# How to make sidebar using framework in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to material UI, I want Navbar and sidebar as different components. I've created Navbar component but unable to create sidebar as separate component. Can anyone please help me in doing separate component? Here is the link which i'm going through "https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/"

And here is the code snippet - "https://codesandbox.io/s/hshhd", where i want separate sidebar(drawer) component to link with Header component.

Header component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { fade, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Badge from '@material-ui/core/Badge';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import AccountCircle from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
import NotificationsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Notifications';
import MoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoreVert';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  grow: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  title: {
    display: 'none',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      display: 'block',
    },
  },
  search: {
    position: 'relative',
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
    },
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    marginLeft: 0,
    width: '100%',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      marginLeft: theme.spacing(3),
      width: 'auto',
    },
  },
  searchIcon: {
    width: theme.spacing(7),
    height: '100%',
    position: 'absolute',
    pointerEvents: 'none',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  inputRoot: {
    color: 'inherit',
  },
  inputInput: {
    padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 7),
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width'),
    width: '100%',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      width: 200,
    },
  },
  sectionDesktop: {
    display: 'none',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      display: 'flex',
    },
  },
  sectionMobile: {
    display: 'flex',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      display: 'none',
    },
  },
}));

const Header = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const [mobileMoreAnchorEl, setMobileMoreAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const isMenuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const isMobileMenuOpen = Boolean(mobileMoreAnchorEl);

  const handleProfileMenuOpen = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleMobileMenuClose = () => {
    setMobileMoreAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const handleMenuClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
    handleMobileMenuClose();
  };

  const handleMobileMenuOpen = event => {
    setMobileMoreAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const menuId = 'primary-search-account-menu';
  const renderMenu = (
    <Menu
      anchorEl={anchorEl}
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
      id={menuId}
      keepMounted
      transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
      open={isMenuOpen}
      onClose={handleMenuClose}
    >
      <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>My account</MenuItem>
    </Menu>
  );

  const mobileMenuId = 'primary-search-account-menu-mobile';
  const renderMobileMenu = (
    <Menu
      anchorEl={mobileMoreAnchorEl}
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
      id={mobileMenuId}
      keepMounted
      transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
      open={isMobileMenuOpen}
      onClose={handleMobileMenuClose}
    >
      <MenuItem>
        <IconButton aria-label="show 11 new notifications" color="inherit">
          <Badge badgeContent={17} color="secondary">
            <NotificationsIcon />
          </Badge>
        </IconButton>
        <p>Notifications</p>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}>
        <IconButton
          aria-label="account of current user"
          aria-controls="primary-search-account-menu"
          aria-haspopup="true"
          color="inherit"
        >
          <AccountCircle />
        </IconButton>
        <p>Profile</p>
      </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
  );

  return (
    <div className={classes.grow}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            edge="start"
            className={classes.menuButton}
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>

          <div className={classes.grow} />
          <div className={classes.sectionDesktop}>
            <IconButton aria-label="show 17 new notifications" color="inherit">
              <Badge badgeContent={17} color="secondary">
                <NotificationsIcon />
              </Badge>
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton
              edge="end"
              aria-label="account of current user"
              aria-controls={menuId}
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <AccountCircle />
            </IconButton>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.sectionMobile}>
            <IconButton
              aria-label="show more"
              aria-controls={mobileMenuId}
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleMobileMenuOpen}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <MoreIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </div>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      {renderMobileMenu}
      {renderMenu}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you were new to it,, I thought I go a little extra to let you see the possibilities and arguably, possible better practices. I have seperated your whole code into 3 parts : Your main component (App), then the content (Content) and then the side menu/App Bar (SideMenu).

```
import React from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import ChevronLeftIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import InboxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox";
import MailIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Mail";

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex"
  },
  appBar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["width", "margin"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    })
  },
  appBarShift: {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["width", "margin"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    })
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: 36
  },
  hide: {
    display: "none"
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
    whiteSpace: "nowrap"
  },
  drawerOpen: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    })
  },
  drawerClose: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    }),
    overflowX: "hidden",
    width: theme.spacing(7) + 1,
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      width: theme.spacing(9) + 1
    }
  },
  toolbar: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3)
  }
}));

// This is the component that controls what to show
export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBarMenu />
      <Content />
    </div>
  );
}

// This is the content component
function Content() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <main className={classes.content}>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        <Typography paragraph>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus
          dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel. Risus at
          ultrices mi tempus imperdiet. Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum
          quisque non tellus. Convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit
          laoreet id donec ultrices. Odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean sed
          adipiscing. Amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies
          integer quis. Cursus euismod quis viverra nibh cras. Metus vulputate
          eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo. Mauris commodo
          quis imperdiet massa tincidunt. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat
          vivamus at augue. At augue eget arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur
          lorem. Velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt. Lorem donec massa sapien
          faucibus et molestie ac.
        </Typography>
        <Typography paragraph>
          Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit. Fringilla est
          ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam. Pulvinar
          elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt. Ornare suspendisse
          sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus. Purus sit amet volutpat consequat
          mauris. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi. Euismod lacinia at quis
          risus sed vulputate odio. Morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas
          purus viverra accumsan in. In hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non
          tellus orci ac. Pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor. Habitant
          morbi tristique senectus et. Adipiscing elit duis tristique
          sollicitudin nibh sit. Ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis
          eleifend. Commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis. Nulla
          posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.
        </Typography>
      </main>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

// This is the appbar component
function AppBarMenu() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
          [classes.appBarShift]: open
        })}
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            className={clsx(classes.menuButton, {
              [classes.hide]: open
            })}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
            Mini variant drawer
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        variant="permanent"
        className={clsx(classes.drawer, {
          [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
          [classes.drawerClose]: !open
        })}
        classes={{
          paper: clsx({
            [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
            [classes.drawerClose]: !open
          })
        }}
      >
        <div className={classes.toolbar}>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            {theme.direction === "rtl" ? (
              <ChevronRightIcon />
            ) : (
              <ChevronLeftIcon />
            )}
          </IconButton>
        </div>
        <Divider />
        <SideMenu />
      </Drawer>
    </div>
  );
}

// This is the sidemenu component
function SideMenu() {
  return (
    <div>
      <List>
        {["Inbox", "Starred", "Send email", "Drafts"].map((text, index) => (
          <ListItem button key={text}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={text} />
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
      <Divider />
      <List>
        {["All mail", "Trash", "Spam"].map((text, index) => (
          <ListItem button key={text}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={text} />
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is also a link to the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ccf27

Comment: Hi, this is nice but I want only AppBar and Sidebar as a sparate components and those two components i could call in App.js component

Comment: So you want only the sidebar and appbar as seperate components calling into the main app?

Comment: Yes, Correct :)

Comment: Edited my answer. please check and let me know

Comment: Thank you sooo much :). Thank you for helping me in this issue :).

Comment: I'm wondering, Is it a responsive sidebar and Appbar. If no, then could you please assist me how to make it?

Comment: I believe material-ui designs are quite responsive so it should be. You may have to do a few modifications depending on your project but over than that, you are good to go.